# How to make method call another one in classes?

Tags: c#, methods, call

Now I have two classes `allmethods.cs` and `caller.cs`.

I have some methods in class `allmethods.cs`. I want to write code in `caller.cs` in order to call a certain method in the `allmethods` class.

Example on code:

```
public class allmethods
public static void Method1()
{
    // Method1
}

public static void Method2()
{
    // Method2
}

class caller
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // I want to write a code here to call Method2 for example from allmethods Class
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Because the `Method2` is static, all you have to do is call like this:

```
public class AllMethods
{
    public static void Method2()
    {
        // code here
    }
}

class Caller
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AllMethods.Method2();
    }
}
```

If they are in different namespaces you will also need to add the namespace of `AllMethods` to caller.cs in a `using` statement.

If you wanted to call an instance method (non-static), you'd need an instance of the class to call the method on. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void InstanceMethod() 
    { 
        // ...
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var instance = new MyClass();
    instance.InstanceMethod();
}
```

**Update**

As of C# 6, you can now also achieve this with `using static` directive to call static methods somewhat more gracefully, for example:

```
// AllMethods.cs
namespace Some.Namespace
{
    public class AllMethods
    {
        public static void Method2()
        {
            // code here
        }
    }
}

// Caller.cs
using static Some.Namespace.AllMethods;

namespace Other.Namespace
{
    class Caller
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Method2(); // No need to mention AllMethods here
        }
    }
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)
- [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)
- [`using static` directive (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static)

Comment: I do appreciate this answer a lot, it is such a hard thing for newbs like myself to get their heads around +1.

Comment: This is great! thank you. But how can I execute these methods without using the className before each time I call the function? I have seen somebody do that.

Comment: @SJ10 I think you're referring to the (relatively) new `using static` directive. See my updated answer.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Ah yes, thank you! this clears up some confusion of the code I have been reading.