# How to make method call another method in the same class?

Tags: c#, class, methods

I have a class called `methods.cs` contains two methods.

For example `method1` and `method2`

I want to make `method2` call `method1`

Code clarification:

```
public static void Method1()
{
// Method1
}

public static void Method2()
{
// Method2
}
```

I want to make `Method2` call `Method1`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Agreed, the two questions you just asked strongly suggest a very new beginner, and should be consulting beginner level content.

Comment: What C# book are you using? You should return it and demand a refund.

Answer (score 14):

Great to see you seeking help! In order to call Method in another Method that is contained in the same Class is pretty simple. Just call it by its name! [Here is a nice little tutorial on Methods](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm) and my example is below!

```
public class ClassName
{
    // Method definition to call in another Method
    public void MethodToCall()
    {
        // Add what you want to be performed here
    }

    // Method definition performing a Call to another Method
    public void MethodCalling()
    {
        // Method being called. Do this by using its Method Name
        // be sure to not forget the semicolon! :) 
        MethodToCall();
    }
}
```

Best of luck to you and hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm missing something from your question, but it should be as simple as this:

```
public static void Method1()
{

}

public static void Method2()
{
    Method1();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is almost exactly the same question as you just asked:

[How to make method call another one in classes C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226444/how-to-make-method-call-another-one-in-classes-c)

But...

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static void Method1()
    {
        // Method1
    }

    public static void Method2()
    {
        Method1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Method2()
{
// Method2
    Method1();
}
```