# calling a variable from one class to another always becomes null

Tags: c#

Below is the sample code

```
public class class1
    {
        public static void emp(string name)
        {
        .....
        value = (value that is returned)
        }
}

public class class2
    {
 public static void studen(string division)
        {
        ...
        }
        }
```

This is how i want to use.  `class2.studen(value);`

Here i need to pass the value that is returned from class1 to the string division of class2.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here function emp and studen are in different class files.

Comment: Nothing is "returned" from class1. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i will be getting a result and will be passing it that result in the variable name "value" in class1

Comment: I do not understand the connection between your question, the code and class1 and class2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make method call another one in classes C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226444/how-to-make-method-call-another-one-in-classes-c)

Comment: its kind of same. but instead of method i want to call the result that is returned from class 1 and pass the result to class2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hatchet mentioned, you're not getting a result from class1. There's a lot of info missing from your post but based on what I *think* you're trying to do, try like this:

```
public class class1
{
    public static string value { get; set; } // use the proper type here if it's not a string

    public static void emp(string name)
    {
        .....
        this.value = (value that is returned)
    }
}

public class class2
{
    public static void studen(string division)
    {
        class1.emp("Hello");
        string class2Var = class1.value; // class2Var will now be "Hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: i just wanna use like this. class2.studen(value);

Comment: If you have `value` as a property of `class1` as I described above, you can call `class2.studen(class1.value)`.