# need to call controller's action method into another class in c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have created one method in a controller, but I need to call this method into anther class and I don't know how to call it.

my sample code :-

```
  public class ReportController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IPermissionService _permissionService;
        private readonly ICompaniesService _companyService;

       public ReportController(IPermissionService permissionService,
            ICompaniesService companyService)
       {
            this._permissionService = permissionService;
            this._companyService = companyService;
       }

        public void Reporting()
        {
            // code
        }
      }


    public class Home {

        public void Execute()
        {
            //I need to execute the Reporting method here
        }

    }
```

I  have tried many things to call my method in another class method but I can't get it to work.

Comment: `new ReportController().Reporting();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make method call another one in classes C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226444/how-to-make-method-call-another-one-in-classes-c)

Comment: Is it possible for you to create Reporting method as static?

Answer (score 4):

It's a bad design way to have some code in a controller who have to be called in several places. Create a class in your project or in an external DLL who contains this code and call this class in the controllers who need this method.

Create a class somewhere (in you project, or in a class library) :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {}

    public void MyMethod()
    {
      // Some code here
    }
}
```

And implement this code in your controllers or classes who need this.

```
public class ReportController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IPermissionService _permissionService;
        private readonly ICompaniesService _companyService;

       public ReportController(IPermissionService permissionService,
            ICompaniesService companyService)
       {
            this._permissionService = permissionService;
            this._companyService = companyService;
       }

        public void Reporting()
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.MyMethod();
        }
}
```

By the way, if your code doesn't need any instance, you can create a static class, like :

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
       // Some code here
    }
}

public class ReportController : BaseController
{
       private readonly IPermissionService _permissionService;
       private readonly ICompaniesService _companyService;

       public ReportController(IPermissionService permissionService,
            ICompaniesService companyService)
       {
            this._permissionService = permissionService;
            this._companyService = companyService;
       }

        public void Reporting()
        {
            MyClass.MyMethod();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of accomplishing this. You are using dependency injection in your controller's constructor, so you have two options of doing this (not sure if I have missed any?):

- Create an instance of each of your services in the calling method and pass these instances through when instantiating the controller, or
- Add a constructor to your home class, set the services and pass them through when instantiating the controller

Option 1:

```
public class Home
{
     public void Execute()
     {
          // Create the variables that are needed by the constructor
          IPermissionService permissionService = new PermissionService();
          ICompaniesService companiesService = new CompaniesService();

          // Create an instance of your controller and pass through
          // the variables created above
          ReportController reportController = new ReportController(permissionService, companiesService);

          // Now that you have an instance of your controller call the method
          reportController.Reporting();
     }
}
```

It works on the same principle as creating an instance of a class and then calling its methods.

Option 2:

```
public class Home
{
     private IPermissionService permissionService;
     private ICompaniesService companiesService;

     public Home(IPermissionService permissionService, ICompaniesService companiesService)
     {
          this.permissionService = permissionService;
          this.companiesService = companiesService;
     }

     public void Execute()
     {
          ReportController reportController = new ReportController(permissionService, companiesService);

          reportController.Reporting();
     }
}
```

Comment: But it's not a good idea to put methods in controller which can be used at multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReportController reportController = new ReportController();
reportController.Reporting();
```

As you would any other class that's method isn't static

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16226459/833070) answer, they go into a lot more detail than I do

Comment: in parameterize contructure i cant crate object of controller and also i have implement BaseController's method into Report Controller so i can't create object on it directly

Comment: you should use DI Library or create an new instance for each param , you can use `StructureMap ` its grate