# how to call function that is in window1 from window2

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Window1, that has a function that sends

```
 public void proba()
        {                 
                MessageBox.Show(this.comboBoxTipUnosa.Text);

        }
```

and on a button click it has

```
Window2 win2= new Window2();
win2.textBoxOne.Text = selectedString;
win2.ShowDialog();
```

If from Window2,on a button click I go with code

```
Window1 win1 = new Window1();
win1.proba();
```

I get a blank messagebox.But if a MessageBox is declared with MessageBox.show("some text"); it works.

This is just a test that I want to get throught.My final idea is to have a method in Window1 that will have the code for sql insert query, with the textboxes from Window1 and I will need that method to be called after a button is clicked on Window2.

Comment: Refactor the common logic out into a separate class that each form can make use of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make method call another one in classes C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226444/how-to-make-method-call-another-one-in-classes-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a *new instance* of `Window1`:

```
Window1 win1 = new Window1();
```

Which means `this.comboBoxTipUnosa.Text` is empty in that instance.

Instead, pass the *existing instance* to `Window2`.  First, expect it on the constructor in `Window2`:

```
private Window1 window1Instance;

public Window2(Window1 window1)
{
    this.window1Instance = window1;
}
```

Then pass the reference when creating `Window2`:

```
Window2 win2 = new Window2(this);
```

Then in `Window2` you can reference the existing instance:

```
this.window1Instance.proba();
```

---

**Note:** This is a *very* "WinForms" way of doing things.  While I won't claim to be a WPF/MVVM expert, you should definitely put some focus into learning the patterns and practices used in WPF.  Treating it like WinForms *can "work"*, but it's clunky and doesn't really make use of the tooling available.