# Not able to call method from class

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a class named test.cs:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using qa.WrapperFactory;

namespace Common.PageObjects
{
    public class Test
    {
        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "xpath")]
        private IWebElement foundElement;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "xpath")]
        private IWebElement EnvironmentLogoElement;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "xpath")]
        private IWebElement UsernameElement;

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "xpath")]
        private IWebElement PasswordElement;

        public void Setup()
        {
            // Set window to full screen
            BrowserFactory.Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            // Clear all cookies
            BrowserFactory.Driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
        }

        public void CheckLoginPage ()
        {
            WaitMethods.WaitForShort(() => foundElement.Displayed);
            Assert.IsTrue(UsernameElement.Displayed);
            Assert.IsTrue(PasswordElement.Displayed);
        }

    }
}
```

I want to call the method public void CheckLoginPage () from the specflow steps. that looks like this:

```
using System.Configuration;
using Common.PageObjects;
using qa.WrapperFactory;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace RegressionTest
{
    [Binding]
    public class SmokeTestSteps
    {
        [Given(@"I go to the HRControlnet login page")]
        public void GivenIGoToTheHRControlnetLoginPage()
        {
            BrowserFactory.InitBrowser("Firefox");
            var subDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"];
            BrowserFactory.LoadApplication(subDomain);
        }

        [Then(@"the result should be on the screen")]
        public void ThenTheResultShouldBeOnTheScreen()
        {
            Test.CheckLoginPage();
        }
    }
}
```

I get now the error on the step ThenTheResultShouldBeOnTheScreen() with 
Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.

I tried to make CheckLoginPage () a static but then all the xpaths give an error.

Anyone can help me out on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to make method call another one in classes C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226444/how-to-make-method-call-another-one-in-classes-c)

Comment: `new Test().CheckLoginPage();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to initialize the class and call the method something like below:

```
  public void ThenTheResultShouldBeOnTheScreen()
    {
        new Test().CheckLoginPage();
    }
```

Comment: This works. But when I execute the test I get the following error in Tests.cs:
object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Either `WaitMethods` or `Assert` is null you might want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779091/what-does-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-mean

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ThenTheResultShouldBeOnTheScreen()
{
    Test test = new Test() // initialize new instance of class
    test.CheckLoginPage()  // call method
}
```

If this doesn't work, you need to add reference